# How to limit the number of lines for a text with HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, text, limit

I have a text that I want to show only 3 or 4 lines of it within a respective width. I use this but it only restricts the text to 1 line only:

```
 text-overflow: ellipsis; 
 max-width: XXXpx;
 white-space: nowrap; 
 overflow:hidden;
```

How can I make that happen?

Comment: Try `height: 5em;`, since 1em is the height of a letter (m) and then `line-height:1.25em;`, so 4 lines are shown. No sure if it'll work, just an idea.

Comment: max-height and line-height should work. The magic number is max-height = line-height * no of lines

Comment: @Francisco Thank you for your suggestion, but nope, it doesn't work.

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana, thank you, i followed your advice and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add height property in style.

```
 style="height:11em;"
```